# C# Dynamic Linq - Case Statements

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I'm having some trouble with Dynamic Linq and I was hoping that someone could help. The problem I'm facing is that I need to order a list in a specific sequence. In SQL I would write this as:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Blah = 'blah' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

How would I accomplish this with Dynamic Linq?

I've tried something like:

```
listToSort.AsQueryable().OrderBy("CASE WHEN Blah = 'blah' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
```

But this returns an error

> No property or field 'CASE' exists in type

This code is generated at runtime as a list of expressions.
So I'm using Dynamic Linq to make use of the expessions as a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
listToSort.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Blah == "blah" ? 1 : 0);
```

You could also use this since a `true` is "more" than a `false`:

```
listToSort.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Blah == "blah");
```

---

It seems that in dynamic LINQ `CASE` or the conditional operator are not supported. But there is another keyword you can use: [`iif`](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/Keywords/iif)

```
listToSort.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy("iif(Blah = 'blah', 1, 0)");
```

[Overview](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/Expressions) of the dynamic LINQ expression methods and keywords.

Comment: I can't do that because the rest of the order by is written as a string.
E.g.

    listToSort.AsQueryable().OrderBy("CASE WHEN Blah = 'blah' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, DateCreated DESC")

Also the order by is being created at runtime, which is why I'm using dynamic linq

Comment: @RianMostert: i have edited my answer. I'm not familiar with dynamic LINQ, so this was interesting for myself also.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was looking for! Also thank you for the links!

Answer (score 0):

A bit old but an interesting question.

Tim sent us to the right direction: we can use nested iif statements to work like a case statement.

My working example: I want to first order by the items which have demand and workers, then by the ones which have only demand, then by the ones which have only workers:

```
iif(Workers.Count > 0 AND Demands.Count > 0, 3, iif(Demands.Count > 0, 2, iif(Workers.Count > 0, 1 , 0)))
```